# Setup/Installation Command-line Arguments

Tags: openssl

I need to install OpenSSL on computers that run my application. To reduce user error I want to automatically select "Copy DLL's to... The OpenSSL binaries (/bin) directory."

Is there any Arguments that the program will take at launch to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need the .DLL's then you should be able to bundle them in your application next to your executable and windows should recognize them. OpenSSL is BSD licenced so you can get away with it.